# Redirect seems to not be working

Tags: javascript, jquery

the problem is that the redirect is not working, it should ignore a search page after login, but it is not. the user clicks on a button to reserve his book, if he is not logged in, a prompt box will ask him for the login information, after login, the user should be redirected to a request form. and now it is taking him to the search page that is defined in the action of the login form.

```
var cookieName = "activeRequest";
var variableName = "requestUrl";
var lifetime = 60;

$(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";
    //$.Jookie.Initialise(cookieName,lifetime);  

    $(".public_request").click(function() {

        //alert("click");
        var url = $(this).attr("id");

        store(url);
        //alert(url);
        //return false;   
    });
});


//store the request link

function store(url) {
    "use strict";
    $.Jookie.Initialise(cookieName, lifetime);
    $.Jookie.Set(cookieName, variableName, url);


}
//check for a active request

function checkForRequest() {
    "use strict";
    $.Jookie.Initialise(cookieName, lifetime);
    var reqURL = $.Jookie.Get(cookieName, variableName);

    //check the response and see if there was one
    if (reqURL === undefined) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        deleteCookie();
        redirect(reqURL);

    }
}

//redirect to request
function redirect(url) {
    "use strict";
    window.location = url;
}

//delete an active request after redirect
function deleteCookie() {
    "use strict";
    $.Jookie.Initialise(cookieName, lifetime);
    $.Jookie.Unset(cookieName, variableName);
}
```

Comment: Aren't we encouraged to use window.location.href?

Comment: Is there some code missing? The only thing this script currently does is execute the `store` function upon `click`ing the `public_request` element... and that's about it. Can't really help you until you explain it a little better and include the relevant code.

Comment: I don't know if there is a code that is missing but the best way to explain it is to follow these steps :

Comment: 1 go to maat.minisisinc.com/norfolk/index.html

Comment: search for test then click on the reserve button  and enter 22001000049926 for id and 1904 for pin, you will be directed to a search form and then wait some seconds and you will taked to the request form, what I want to achieve is that you go straight to the request form instead of the search form then request form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(reqURL === undefined)
```

should be

```
if (typeof(reqURL) == "undefined")
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I just tried your approach and it doesn't seem to make any difference.